# Oracle SQL Slow Join

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been dealing with a slow running query, similar to the following

```
select
    count(*)
from
    a
    join b
        on a.akey = b.akey
    join c 
        on b.bkey = c.bkey
    left join d
        on c.ykey = d.ykey
        and b.xkey = d.xkey
where
    a.idkey = 'someid'
```

This query takes 130s to run for 'someid'

If I remove either condition of the left join, the query runs in <1s.

I've determined the issue for this particular record (someid). There are a huge number of matching `d.xkey` values (~5 000 000). I've done some tests and modifying the relevant `d.xkey` values for this record to more unique values improves run time to <1s.

This is the fix I'm currently using.

```
select
    count(*)
from
    a
    join b
        on a.akey = b.akey
    join c 
        on b.bkey = c.bkey
    left join d
        on c.ykey = d.ykey
where
    a.idkey = 'someid'
    and (
        b.xkey = d.xkey
        OR b.xkey is null
        OR not exists (
            select
                dd.xkey
            from
                d dd
            where
                dd.xkey = b.xkey
                and dd.ykey = c.ykey
        )
    )
```

This query runs in less than 1s.

My question is, why is this so much faster than the left join?

Is my new query equivalent to the old one in terms of results?

Comment: Please show an explain plan. http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Explain_Plan

Comment: SQL Monitor reports of the two queries would be more beneficial than an explain plan. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/sqlmonitor-084401.html

Comment: @BobC - undoubtedly so, but SQL Monitor requires the  Oracle Tuning Pack, which is a chargeable extra on the Enterprise Edition. You should not advise people to use this feature unless you're sure they work for an organisation which has licensed the pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the join onto `d` is efficient for either `b.xkey` or `c.ykey` alone (these names are appallingly subtle), but not when both are combined, it's probably because it is able to use an index on `d` for each one individually, but there is no combined index available.

The second example you've posted with the `NOT EXISTS` clause is almost unfathomable, but crucially it includes extra logic and is not directly equivalent to the `LEFT JOIN` in the first example.

In the `WHERE` clause of your second example, you permit rows to be included that have been left-joined between `c` and `d` where `b.xkey` is `null`, whereas in your first example, the joining of these rows would never have occurred (because `b.xkey` being `null` would have precluded the left-join). This means d has already possibly multiplied the rows in the results set improperly, which cannot be filtered by the where-clause (because without a `ROW_NUMBER` function, the where-clause cannot differentiate between each improper match - and can only filter either all or none of them, rather than reducing them back down to a single row), so the two queries can be deemed not logically identical on this ground alone.

It's otherwise difficult to reason precisely about what the combined effect of the whole where-clause is, and how it might be interacting with the other constraints and the underlying data to allow the query to perform better (despite ostensibly having to perform a similar lookup as the left-join did in the first example). If you are getting identical results from both queries, I would say it is only because of a dangerous coincidence in the data, while the logical constraints imposed by the two queries are fundamentally different.

Comment: You are right, there was no index created on the combined key.

Comment: @Jamie, glad you got it sorted. Don't forget to mark as answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

Both queries don't seems logically equal. You can understand simply with condition

OR b.xkey is null .
a=b and b=c and c=d(+)

If you are taking OR b.xkey is null then a=b is filtering out some data.
Actually both are very much different.